# Reading integers from a text file in C line by line and storing them in an array

Tags: c, arrays, file

I am new to C and have been trying to do this for a while now.

I need to read the integer values from a text file that has :

G = 10

P = 5

Gayle: 1,2,3,4

Price: 4,3,5,6.6

Need to pick out the Gayle and Price values and store them in 2 seperate arrays and store the G and P values in 2 separate variables.

So far I have done :

```
FILE* file = fopen(abc.txt, "r");
//for gayle values
int g_array[100];
int i=0;
int gayle_val;
while(fscanf("%d", &gayle_val)==1)
{
    g_array[i]=gayle_val;
}
//for price values
int p_array[100];
int i=0;
int price_val;
while(fscanf("%d", &price_val)==1)
{
    p_array[i]=price_val;
}
//for G and P values
```

How do I combine the searches for the 4 lines such that the read is done line by line and values stored accordingly ?

Thank you so much in advance !

Comment: Price sample include 6.6. convert to `int`?

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered before and I'm pretty sure it was suggested to you as the question was typed:

[image: Literally to the left of your question]

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to give you a code sample but instead am going to advise you on what could be done to get the contents of the file to be inserted in a single array rather than one.

Try to create a 2D array instead and assigning the values to it rather than having multiple arrays and use a `FOR` loop to do so.

Comment: The thing is I have to use the values separately in another part of the code. So taking them into a single 2d array would be useful ?

Answer (score 0):

simple E.G.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    int gayle_val, g_array[100], g_count, p_count;
    float price_val, p_array[100];
    int i;
    char line_buff[128], *p;
    FILE *file = fopen("abc.txt", "r");
    while(NULL!=fgets(line_buff, sizeof(line_buff), file)){
        if(strncmp("G = ", line_buff, 4) == 0){//simple match
            gayle_val = atoi(line_buff + 4);
        } else if(strncmp("P = ", line_buff, 4) == 0){
            price_val = atof(line_buff + 4);
        } else if(strncmp("Gayle: ", line_buff, 7) == 0){
            g_count = 0;
            for(p = line_buff + 7;NULL!=(p=strtok(p, ","));p=NULL){
                g_array[g_count++] = atoi(p);
            }
        } else if(strncmp("Price: ", line_buff, 7) == 0){
            p_count = 0;
            for(p = line_buff + 7;NULL!=(p=strtok(p, ","));p=NULL){
                p_array[p_count++] = atof(p);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

    //check print
    printf("gayle_val: %d\n", gayle_val);
    printf("gayle: ");
    for(i = 0;i<g_count;++i)
        printf("%d ", g_array[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("price_val: %g\n", price_val);
    printf("price: ");
    for(i = 0;i<p_count;++i)
        printf("%g ", p_array[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```